# Class Registration through google form

Tags: javascript, forms, google-sheets

I am trying to make a google form linked with a google sheet for class registration. As the process goes right now, they want students to pick their classes and then have those go through the teachers to get passed or rejected. The only issue I am currently having is separating the data into a different sheet depending on what teacher they have as soon as the form is submitted, I recently found a code that can sort it like this but there must be some user input other than the form response for this to work:

is there any way to make it automatically shift the row to a new sheet if the user presses the "submit form" button on the form and submits it.

```js
/**
 * Moves row of data to another spreadsheet based on criteria in column 6 to sheet with same name as the value in column 4.
*/

function onEdit(e) {
  // see Sheet event objects docs
  // https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events
  var ss = e.source;
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var r = e.range;
  
  // to let you modify where the action and move columns are in the form responses sheet
  var actionCol = 4;
  var nameCol = 6;

  // Get the row and column of the active cell.
  var rowIndex = r.getRowIndex();
  var colIndex = r.getColumnIndex();
  
  // Get the number of columns in the active sheet.
  // -1 to drop our action/status column
  var colNumber = s.getLastColumn()-1;
  
  // if our action/status col is changed to ok do stuff
  if (e.value == "submit form" && colIndex == actionCol) {
    // get our target sheet name - in this example we are using the priority column
    var targetSheet = s.getRange(rowIndex, nameCol).getValue();
    // if the sheet exists do more stuff
    if (ss.getSheetByName(targetSheet)) { 
      // set our target sheet and target range
      var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(targetSheet);
      var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, colNumber);
      // get our source range/row
      var sourceRange = s.getRange(rowIndex, 1, 1, colNumber);
      // new sheets says: 'Cannot cut from form data. Use copy instead.' 
      sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange);

    }
  }
}
```

I hope that makes sense,
Joseph

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15P-SpC31qdzfBUsN1TBvRHFn5iptdDX_9T4UlNPMDuk/edit#gid=238259321

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need custom code unless you want to be able to edit the data in the second sheet.  You can use the =QUERY() function to put all the entries for a given teacher in that sheet.  So in the thodges sheet, in cell A1, place:

```
=QUERY("Form Responses 6"!A1:M, "select * where F = 'thodges', 1)
```

This will display the entries in the order entered and you can add additional columns for the teacher's actions or use.

If you only want a list and want the items in a specific order, you can use other syntax such as adding "order by C" or other syntax as found on the [Query() help page.](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)

Otherwise, change your function name to something other than OnEdit and make it [On Form Submit Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).